# Call jQuery won't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, html

I'm trying jQuery for the first time on my website and it doesn't work. I've been trying hundreds of things for about 10 hours now and today I have much more grey hair =). The most simple snippet I found is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#msgid1").html("This is Hello World by JQuery 1<BR>");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#msgid2").html("This is Hello World by JQuery 2<BR>");
    });

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('msgid3').innerHTML = "This is Hello World by JavaScript";
    };

</script>

This is Hello World by HTML

<div id="msgid1">
</div>

<div id="msgid2">
</div>

<div id="msgid3">
</div>
```

I put that in my `<body>`. The result is :

```
This is Hello World by HTML
This is Hello World by JavaScript
```

And the jQuery calls don't work for me. Maybe it has something to do with my `<head>`?

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What do you think?

Comment: jQuery is a library - not something built intrinsically into browsers. Just to be clear, have you included it and can you verify that it is loading properly?

Comment: Can you post it on jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: Seems like jQuery isn't being loaded correctly, as your code works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/Wp4Nb/).

Comment: Can you swap out `@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")` for `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: What does the HTML look like when the page loads? How are you loading jQuery? Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I'm in development mode, so the feature is tested locally and not on internet yet

Comment: What browser are you using? Most have developer tools that will give you more information on the error.

Comment: The page doesn't return an error. I use Chrome. I'll give a try on Firefox. I can't tell the HTML as in development mode, the page source only returns the code I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just found the solution.

There seems to be an issue whene these lines are not very next to each other

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

By simply changing the order of the lines, the two jQuery output lines suddenly appeared!

Thank you all for you help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you either have your script pointing to jQuery beneath this script block, or completely absent.  You need to "load" jQuery before you try to use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#msgid1").html("This is Hello World by JQuery 1<BR>");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#msgid2").html("This is Hello World by JQuery 2<BR>");
    });

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('msgid3').innerHTML = "This is Hello World by JavaScript";
    };

</script>
```

The script tag I added points to the Google CDN, but you can also download it locally and reference it locally:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried with the url and with it locally. No success yet. I have my <script> block in the <head> and its usage in the body.

Comment: Maybe your MVC tags are wrong.  Have you tried it with a raw script tag, exactly as I have it in my answer—pointing to google?  Paste that into your `<head>`, comment out the mvc tag, and see if that works.

Comment: I see that from an empty view, it works. I guess something may not be compatible in what I did. I'll rebuild the view from scratch and follow up on what causes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Mathieu - Yeah, it sounds like you're having some MVC issues, not jQuery.  If it doesn't work, make sure you view source to see **exactly** what MVC is spitting out.